# XML to CSV with nested and definite elements in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, csv, data-conversion

I need to convert my xml file to csv Format. But I in csv file I need not all Information fron the XML, just 2 elements (IP Address and id from device).

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use Data::Dumper;
 use XML::Simple;

  #Elements, that I want see in my csv
  my @Fields = qw{id, ipAddress};

  open(my $out, '>', 'output.csv') or die "Output: $!\n";
  print $out join(',', @Fields) . "\n";

  my $xml = XMLin('input.xml', ForceArray => ['entity']);
  foreach my $entity (@{$xml->{entity}}) {
  no warnings;
  print $out join(',', map{$_->{content}} @{$entity}{@Fields}) . "\n";
```

Input.xml

---

```
      <?xml version="1.0" ?>
          <queryResponse last="41" first="0" count="42" type="Devices" responseType="listEntityInstances" requestUrl="https://hostname/webacs/api/v1/data/Devices?.full=true" rootUrl="https://hostname/webacs/api/v1/data">
             <entity dtoType="devicesDTO" type="Devices" url="https://hostname/webacs/api/v1/data/Devices/20">
               <devicesDTO displayName="20" id="20">
               <clearedAlarms>1</clearedAlarms>
               <collectionDetail>&lt;status&gt;&lt;general code="SUCCESS"/&gt;&lt;/status&gt;</collectionDetail>
               <collectionTime>2017-03-30T09:47:07.606+02:00</collectionTime>
               <creationTime>2016-02-29T17:32:13.116+01:00</creationTime>
               <ipAddress>1.1.1.1</ipAddress>
               <location> </location>
               <majorAlarms>0</majorAlarms>
                <softwareType>IOS</softwareType>
                <softwareVersion>12.2(55)SE9</softwareVersion>
                <warningAlarms>0</warningAlarms>
             </devicesDTO>
          </entity>
          <entity dtoType="devicesDTO" type="Devices" url="https://hostname/webacs/api/v1/data/Devices/21">
               <devicesDTO displayName="21" id="21">
               <clearedAlarms>1</clearedAlarms>
               <collectionDetail>&lt;status&gt;&lt;general code="SUCCESS"/&gt;&lt;/status&gt;</collectionDetail>
               <collectionTime>2017-03-30T09:47:07.606+02:00</collectionTime>
               <creationTime>2016-02-29T17:32:13.116+01:00</creationTime>
               <ipAddress>2.2.2.2</ipAddress>
               <location> </location>
               <majorAlarms>0</majorAlarms>
                <softwareType>IOS</softwareType>
                <softwareVersion>12.2(55)SE9</softwareVersion>
                <warningAlarms>0</warningAlarms>
             </devicesDTO>
          </entity>
        </queryResponse>
```

As result I have

```
 id, ipAddress
 ,
 ,
```

I am not sure that:

```
     my $xml = XMLin('input.xml', ForceArray => ['entity']);
     foreach my $entity (@{$xml->{entity}})
```

is right in my case. Should I do it with tag **entity**?

Comment: You should not use XML::Simple in new code. It's not simple, often wrong and the documentation suggests to not use it.

Comment: The `ipAddress` is an _element_, not an _attribute_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with XML::Simple, it's always a good idea to use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) **first** to look at the data structure.

```
foreach my $entity ( @{ $xml->{entity} } ) {
    print Dumper $entity;
```

This will show you:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'url' => 'https://hostname/webacs/api/v1/data/Devices/20',
          'type' => 'Devices',
          'dtoType' => 'devicesDTO',
          'devicesDTO' => {
                          'displayName' => '20',
                          'creationTime' => '2016-02-29T17:32:13.116+01:00',
                          'warningAlarms' => '0',
                          'ipAddress' => '1.1.1.1',
                          'clearedAlarms' => '1',
                          'majorAlarms' => '0',
                          'collectionDetail' => '<status><general code="SUCCESS"/></status>',
                          'location' => {},
                          'collectionTime' => '2017-03-30T09:47:07.606+02:00',
                          'softwareType' => 'IOS',
                          'id' => '20',
                          'softwareVersion' => '12.2(55)SE9'
                        }
        };
```

So it's quite clear that your `@Fields` are in the wrong place. Those keys are not in `$entity` directly, but rather in `$entity->{devicesDTO}`.

There is also no need to use `$_->{content}` with the `map`. In fact, there are no `content` keys in that data structure.

```
foreach my $entity ( @{ $xml->{entity} } ) {
    print join( ',', @{ $entity->{devicesDTO} }{@Fields} ) . "\n";
}
```

This will produce the output

```
id,ipAddress
20,1.1.1.1
21,2.2.2.2
```

---

Note that you have a stray comma in your `qw{}` that you don't need. The idea of `qw` is that you do not need to use commas. You should also decide if you want your variables to have lower case letters or not. Mixing that is bad style, and the convention in Perl is to use snake case.

```
my @fields = qw{id ipAddress};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for advise! It works! But my file output.csv is empty.

Should I write 
           `open(my $out, '>', 'output.csv') or die "Output: $!\n";
             print $out join(',', @Fields) . "\n";`
at the end of script?

Comment: @StayCalm you didn't show your full code, so I don't know. If you have a follow up question, please ask it as new question.

Comment: This peace of code is from that one, I've posted :)